# rails 5 API low-level caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rails-api

I am a bit confused regarding Rails API caching. I am using JSONAPI spec and fast_jsonapi gem and trying to cache the vehicle itself on show action and if there are params coming over like `include=service_notes,service_alerts` then I would like to cache those too. This is my initial approach but not sure if it is right.

I have 2 main issues:

1. For the vehicle caching itself is there a better approach than my vehicle = Vehicle.find_cached(params[:id]). This is not using updated_at but an after save callback to update the cache if vehicle has been updated. I just don't see if I could somehow use sth like `Rails.cache.fetch(["vehicles", vehicle], version: vehicle.updated_at)` as it is proposed here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29092 since this needs the vehicle instance. As you see the `set_vehicle` controller method is pretty awkward.
2. Does this `Rails.cache.fetch(['vehicles', vehicle, include_params], version: vehicle.updated_at)` make any sense? I am trying to cache the query based on the different include params. Maybe it is overkill and I could just include everything and cache it that way like:

   Rails.cache.fetch(['vehicles', vehicle, 'with_includes'], version: vehicle.updated_at) do
     Vehicle.includes(:vehicle_alerts, :service_notes, :service_intervals).find(params[:id])
   end

What is the correct way to handle caching here?

`service_note.rb` setup same for `service_interval.rb` and `vehicle_alert.rb`

```
class ServiceNote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vehicle, touch: true
end
```

vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :update_cache
  has_many :vehicle_alerts, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :service_notes, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :service_intervals, dependent: :delete_all

  def update_cache
    Rails.cache.write(['vehicles', vehicle_id], self)
  end

  def self.find_cached(vehicle_id)
    Rails.cache.fetch(['vehicles', vehicle_id]) { find(vehicle_id) }
  end
end
```

vehicles_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_vehicle, only: [:show]

def show
  render json: VehicleSerializer.new(@vehicle, options).serialized_json
end

private

def set_vehicle
  vehicle = Vehicle.find_cached(params[:id])

  @vehicle = Rails.cache.fetch(['vehicles', vehicle, include_params], version: vehicle.updated_at) do
    Vehicle.includes(include_params).find(params[:id])
  end

  authorize @vehicle
end
```

vehicle_serializer.rb (with fast_jsonapi gem)

```
# same for :service_notes and :vehicle_alerts
has_many :service_intervals do |vehicle, params|
  if params[:include] && params[:include].include?(:service_intervals)
    vehicle.service_intervals
  end
end
```

Comment: Below links will help you: [https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/caching.md] - [https://robots.thoughtbot.com/fast-json-apis-in-rails-with-key-based-caches-and] - [https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#caching]

Comment: I'm thinking what you really want here is not low level caching - rather you want to use ETags combined with a reverse proxy to handle caching on the HTTP layer.  https://robots.thoughtbot.com/take-control-of-your-http-caching-in-rails

Comment: I couldn't decide which type of caching is the best here. Resources are confusing unfortunately. If I understand correctly when it comes to key-based cache exp you will always have to look up the instance because you need the `updated_at`. So basically you win nothing if the show action is simple. On the other hand if you do cache update manually( like I do  `after_save :update_cache`) then you don't need to lookup the `updated_at`. As the app grows more complex though it could be better to use the key-based expiration as that updated_at lookup is cheaper and you don't screw up the cache exp.